# How does page replacement policies work for systems with a TLB?

Tags: operating-system, virtual-memory, tlb

If we have a system with a TLB, how is page replacement done? Does the computer directly replace an entry in TLB and evict it from memory, or do we somehow keep the entry consistent in TLB and page table? If we synchronize the PTEs somehow, do we avoid replacing PTEs that are currently in TLB from being evicted even if the reference bit is 0?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, TLB's tend to be hardware-based; meaning they probably use some form of LRU+ mapping, but the exact details are decided by hardware manufacturers. The most I think you can do in the Linux kernel is just flush things out of the TLB yourself. See [this](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/core-api/cachetlb.html)

Comment: Yep, it seems like they just flush it. Thank you so much for the help.